# Обновление DIV после загрузки страницы

Tags: jquery

Как с помощью jQuery обновить DIV после загрузки страницы?

Comment: `$('div').html('Новое содержимое')`

Comment: что значит "обновить после перезагрузки?" чем обновить?

Comment: может так `$(function(){ $('div').html('Новое содержимое'); })`

Comment: После выполнения запроса данные формы (со множеством полей в виде чекбоксов) должны записаться в базу данных, далее после сравнения с другими таблицами, отобразиться обратно на форме (в виде отмеченных чекбоксов), но без повтрного выполнения запроса.

Comment: вам надо использовать AJAX запросы к базе и вставить значение в  чекбоксы, вам надо попробовать написать самому данный код.

Comment: либо вопрос как то странно задан , либо я не пойму что надо сделать , ка они обратно попадают в див

Comment: Понимаю, но быстрота сейчас на первом месте для демонстрации, потом буду дорабатывать. Поэтому для данного этапа хочу обойтись повторным оборажением DIV без повторной перезагрузки страницы. После обновления данные отображаются на форме, но теряется результат расчёта и графики...

Comment: Данные с формы записываются в базу, затем считываются повторно с некоторой обработкой (связь с другими таблицами и проверка) и отображаются на форме, как последний результат...

Comment: На данном этапе достаточно понять, как с помощью jQuery обновить DIV после загрузки страницы, чтобы вытянуть только что записанные данные?

Comment: Ну тогда первый коментарий, то что нужно, только вместо $('div') нужно задать правильный селектор

Comment: Не получается... Можно работающий пример?